# jq select items where a property contains the value of another property

Tags: json, jq

I'm trying to filter for items from a list that contain the values of other properties in the same object.

Example of the data.json:

```
{ result: 
  [
    { name: 'foo', text: 'my name is foo' },
    { name: 'bar', text: 'my name is baz' },
  ]
}
```

What I've tried:

```
cat data.json | jq '.result[] | select(.text | ascii_downcase | contains(.name))'
```

However it throws the following error:
`Cannot index string with string`

Is there a way in jq to select based on a dynamic property rather than a string literal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your JSON looks more like this (strings in double quotes, no comma after the last array item):

```json
{ "result": 
  [
    { "name": "foo", "text": "my name is foo" },
    { "name": "bar", "text": "my name is baz" }
  ]
}
```

When going into `.text`, you have lost the context from which you can access `.name`. You could save it (or directly the desired value) in a variable and reference it when needed:

```sh
jq '.result[] | select(.name as $name | .text | ascii_downcase | contains($name))'
```

```json
{
  "name": "foo",
  "text": "my name is foo"
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/60E0riPlQW)